# breaking change in angular 1.5.9 $location.hashPrefix

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It looks like the default `$location.hashPrefix` was "" (empty string) until [1.5.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/guide/$location), however, it was changed to "!" in [1.5.9](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location). Unfortunately, my code has a lot of places like `<a ng-ref="/Customer#/{{customerId}}>` that is now breaking. Is there a *global* way to handle this? Or the only way is to go through the whole codebase in preparation for 1.5.9? FWIW, I am curious what was the rationale for this - can't find a discussion anywhere...

Comment: use `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` to set it to what you want.

Comment: I was wondering if this is the right time to take the plunge and move to hashbang URLs...

Comment: The angular [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) links to [aa077e](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52) and [#13812](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13812) for the rationale. The reason appears to be to avoid confusion and for consistency with [HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the default hasPrefix changed from `""` to `"!"`.

If you set your hasPrefix to an empty string like `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` routes like `/Customer/#/{{customerId}}` that worked in 1.5.8 would work start resolving again in 1.5.9, from the testing that I have done, though they it will still render like `/Customer/#!/1`

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned back in September, we decided to take the plunge and move to hashbang URLs